# What language is this script written in?

Tags: vb.net, language-agnostic, vb6, vbscript

```
CreateObject("Wscript.Shell").Run "taskkill /f /t /im oovoo.exe", 0, False
```

I know it is some variation of Visual Basic, and I know it's not .NET. Is it VB6, or some sort of other VB scripting language I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [VBScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VBScript) (typically with a .vbs extension).

Comment: Correct, and also completely superfluous because the VBS is only executing a batch command.  You can have avoid VBS altogether and just used a .bat extension with the command portion that is in quotes.

Comment: I only have it in VBScript so cmd doesn't flash open when I kill the task

Answer (score 3):

While this could be VBScript, it is also an acceptable and legitimate VB6 code snippet.